# Sql Agent Not Working On System Date Change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I am facing issue with sql agent , on changing the server date it does not start at its schedule time while job is schedule daily at fixed time. No logs are found on this . This issue also occurs while system date has been changed to its real date . I have to restart the sql agent after that to invoke the job at its schedule time.

Comment: Why would you want to change server date? What was the date and what did you change it to?

Comment: there was some application requirement for the server date change, it was 6 months later from current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Agent scheduled jobs will have last run date/time and next run date/time. Each time the jobs run, these values get updated. Please look in MSDB and you will see these details. You can also look in Job history.

When you manually reset the system clock to a date later than now, then your next run date/time will be in the past. As you have mentioned, bouncing the agent service should start the jobs again.

Raj

Comment: Thanks Raj. It was a great help. But this is my concern that on day 1 job executed at 9PM and on day 2 10 AM date was changed and again reset to 2 PM on the day 2 . Still job not executed at its schedule time.